# Generate JSON schema in Python

Tags: python, json, web-services

I am working on a project to extract data from web services.  I'd like to analyze the JSON response I'm getting from these various calls, such that I can understand the structure of the response I'm getting.

For example, look at the json this response provides: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

I'm hoping to generate a "schema" or skeleton of this response to look something like the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": "Number",
    "name": "String",
    "username": "String",
    "email": "String",
    "address": {
      "street": "String",
      "suite": "String",
      "city": "String",
      "zipcode": "String",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "Number",
        "lng": "Number"
      }
    },
    "phone": "String",
    "website": "String",
    "company": {
      "name": "String",
      "catchPhrase": "String",
      "bs": "String"
    }
]
```

Does anyone know of a way I can get to this with existing standard or 3rd party modules?  I've done significant searching without any luck.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a simple way you can get the data structure you are after with existing standard or 3rd party modules.

Just as an idea - as there are no other replies - you may be able to try something similar to the following, but with more care taken to traverse the nested dictionaries:

```
for i in range(len(json_parsed)):
    for k,v in json_parsed[i].items():
        print(k, str(type(v)).replace("<class", "").replace('>',""))

    id  'int'
    username  'str'
    website  'str'
    address  'dict'
    email  'str'
    phone  'str'
    company  'dict'
    name  'str'
    id  'int'
    username  'str'
    website  'str'
    address  'dict'
    email  'str'
    phone  'str'
    company  'dict'
    name  'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution. It goes over a Python dictionary, the kind you get when you do:

```
data = requests.get(...)
results = data.json()
```

I'm still working on it, namely deep checking that complex elements of a list are the same, so that I could return the `first...` instead of `first, second`.

Here's the code:

```
def schema(d, spacer='  ', indent=0, force=0):
    types = [list, set, dict, tuple]
    open_symbols = ['[', '{', '{', '(']
    close_symbols = [']', '}', '}', ')']
    res = ''
    typ = type(d)
    if typ in types:
        os, cs = list(zip(open_symbols, close_symbols))[types.index(typ)]
        res += f'{spacer * (indent*force)}{os}\n'
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for key, value in d.items():
                res += f'{spacer * (indent+1)}{key}: '
                res += f'{schema(value, spacer, indent+1)}\n'
        else:
            if(typ is set):
                return res[:-1] + (d.pop().__class__.__name__ if len(d) else None) + cs
            else:
                if all(isinstance(x, type(d[0])) for x in d[1:]) and type(d[0]) not in types:
                    return res[:-1] + d[0].__class__.__name__ + cs
                else:
                    for value in d:
                        res += f'{schema(value, spacer, indent+1, 1)}\n'
        res += f'{spacer * indent}{cs}'
    else:
        res = d.__class__.__name__
    return res
```

At a glance, it becomes apparent that:

1. this is derived from my own version of `pprint`, so you have spacing elements; I don't like `pprint`'s output;
2. this is not meant to be exclusive to JSON results and that's why you find `set` and `tuple` in there; lots of other structured types are not contemplated;
3. this returns a `str`, so you use it like this: `print(schema(d))`, where `d` is some Python variable;
4. there is work to be done, namely all those `return`s;

I hope this helps, after all these years.